# Store jsp properties in java

Tags: java, jsp, properties

I have a website with question and answer fields. If you click on a button then some questions will be answered automatically and these answers get loaded from the database via java. Every question field has a property in the .jsp.

I would like to know if it is possible to store these properties in java (in a list for example) and save it in the Form class and then mark the stored properties of the automatically answered fields in .jsp with a colour?

Comment: I'm sure it is.

Comment: @shmosel I guess that it is too but I wonder how

Comment: You can use the session variables to store a list in the jsp/ java, wherever you like.